Can I pre-validate a record in Apex before commiting the data to the database?
I have a component that takes a CSV and parses it to get records from each row. Currently it is difficult to handle for large numbers of fields on the object.
Is there a way to validate all of the records (e.g. valid picklist fields, no missing required fields, no failed validation rules etc) without inserting any so that I can return a list of issues to be fixed before actually loading/attempting to load any data?

Yes. Set a transaction Savepoint, try to insert or update the record, as needed, and then rollback the transaction at the end. Might be very time consuming, and you need to take a look for platform events that might be fired immediately instead of at the end of the transaction.
// create savepoint 
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

// do your things with the record

// rollback so they are not persisted on the database
Database.rollback(sp);

To handle each row error individually you will want to use the Database class' methods, such as .insert, .upsert or .update so that they return a Database.SaveResult for each row so you can use the .getErrors() method to get the errors for each item.
